# Finding the appropriate word (related to selling and buying)

Tags: word-request

I'm trying to find a verb that means "To persuade the seller to sell something with a lower price"

For example, John went to buy a new phone. He had 200$. The phone was 240$. So he tried to buy the phone with 200$.

Comment: bargaining? Bartering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

- haggle: He haggled with the store to get the price down to $200 (this is more colloquial)
- negotiate: He negotiated with the seller to reduce the price to $200 (this is more formal)
- bargain: He bargained with the seller to lower the price.

"Barter" is related but it actually means something else: trading two commodities for each other without currency. I.e. "John bartered for the phone with his designer purse."

The first two imply success unless you qualify it afterwards, i. e. "... but the store refused to lower the price." "Bargain" in this context has a slight implication of failure.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is [**to talk the seller down**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/talk-down), as in

> John tried to talk the seller down to $200.

(This may be a specifically American usage, from what I can see.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use "bargain" - "He tried bargaining with the seller by offering $200."   I think bartering is often used to mean an exchange that doesn't involve money (e.g. Bartering a kilo of flour for a kilo of sugar"